# How to rename the filename of that folder name and copy all files into one folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to unix . I got a requirement like this .
I have xml folder in the server . In that folder , everyday , i will get different employee details for each employee in one folder .

```
/server/user/home/xml/e1100123/Employeedetails.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100123/Employeesalary.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100123/Employeeleaves.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100123/Employeestatus.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100155/Employeedetails.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100155/Employeesalary.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100155/Employeeleaves.xml
/server/user/home/xml/e1100155/Employeestatus.xml
```

---

I have to group all employees in one folder with filename_employeenumber as shown below .

```
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeedetails-e1100123.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeesalary-e1100123.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeeleaves-e1100123.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeestatus-e1100123.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeedetails-e1100155.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeesalary-e1100155.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeeleaves-e1100155.xml
/server/user/home/xml/allemployees/Employeestatus-e1100155.xml
```

How to write a code in unix shell script ?

Thank you ......
Sai

Comment: `mkdir foldername` will create whatever folders you need. `mv filename newfilename` will rename the file. You can use `mv` to move the file to the new location in addition to renaming it. For example: `mv ~/something.c ~/Documents/mystuff/somethingwithanewname.c`

Comment: If you're wanting to automate all that with a script you'll probably want to familiarize yourself with `awk`

Comment: Yes . I want to write a script because i will have more employeenumber folders . like e1100123, e1100155 , e1100124 , e1100156 etc.,

Comment: Well I'm not going to write your script for you. The tools you'll most likely want for this are `find $PWD` to get your parent working directory, `awk` to parse it for employee number, `mkdir` to create your new folder, and `mv` to move and rename your file. Good luck. `awk`, `sed`, and `regex` can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Do you have the `rename` command in your OS?

Answer (score 0):

Bare bone of your desired script could be like so:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
base_dir=/server/user/home/xml
all_dir=${base_dir}/allemployes
e_dirs=$(ls -d ${base_dir}/e*)
e_files=(Employeedetails.xml Employeesalary.xml Employeestatus.xml Employeeleaves.xml)

if [ ! -d "${base_dir}" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: ${base_dir} doesn't exists!"
fi

if [ ! -d "${all_dir}" ]; then
  echo "INFO: Creating all employees directory at ${all_dir}"
  mkdir "${all_dir}"
fi

for e in ${e_dirs}; do
  pushd "${e}" > /dev/null

  for f in ${e_files[@]}; do
    if [ ! -f ${f} ]; then
      echo "ERROR: Missing ${f} file for employee $(basename ${e})"
    else
      new_file=${all_dir}/${f%.*}-$(basename ${e}).xml
      cp "${e}/${f}" "${new_file}"
    fi
  done

  popd > /dev/null
done
```

Notes:

- Script assumes that in `xml/` folder are only employees folder and every folder starts with lower character **e**, hence we do `e_dirs=$(ls -d ${base_dir}/e*)`
- Script works only with files `Employeedetails.xml Employeesalary.xml Employeestatus.xml Employeeleaves.xml` file, ignoring others, in each employee folder.
- Script creates `allemployes/` folder if it does not exists.
- Script makes copies instead of moving (not destructive), so you can use `mv` instead of `cp`

I haven't tested the script! So please do not run it on live data :). Feel free to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script :

```
#!/bin/bash 

sourceDir=$1
destDir=$2
dirname=$(basename $1) 

if [ ! -d $2 ] ; then 
                mkdir $2 
fi

for I in $sourceDir/*
do 
                fname=$(basename $I) 
                prefix=$(echo $fname | awk -F "." 'NF{NF-=1};1')
                suffix=$(echo $fname | awk -F "." '{print $NF}')
                target="$destDir/$prefix-$dirname.$suffix"
                cp $I $target
                # I use cp(Copy) command , you can replace this to mv(Move) command . 
                echo $target
done
```

Usage :

```
./script.sh  [SOURCEDIR] [DESTDIR]
```

Example :

```
./script.sh /server/user/home/xml/e1100123/  /server/user/home/xml/allemployees/
```